# Which is the best way for universal iOS app splash screen iOS 12?

Tags: ios, xcode

My scenario, I am creating a universal application with multiple view controllers. Here, I used different sizes of  images for `Splash` view controller. Finally, my application size is too high. It’s because of multiple size of images. Now, which is the best way of reducing the app size or any other alternative way available for less image quantity to achieve multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use the largest size image available then inside the splash storyboard or nib ( `LaunchScreen.storyboard` ) . Set the imageview content mode to fit ( `.scaleAspectFit` ) and set the constraints up correctly. Then you only need 1 image

Comment: Could you please provide the size of the image for universal app? @Malcolmn Roberts

Comment: @devmikle Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/ ..  Then maybe pick iphone XS max for the iphone and 12.9 " for ipad so you have 2 images that you use inside the storyboard and then set them to fit

Comment: @Malcolmn Roberts, thanks, that was helpful. Just one single 3x image was sufficient to downsize to different sizes. For me, I used AspectFill instead of AspectFit since on iPhone Plus it was showing some gaps if I used AspectFit when I used iPhone XS Max splash size.

Comment: @greenOrange if you use AspectFill it will stretch your image sometime which makes your image looks bad.

Comment: @green0range, AspectFill will NOT distort the image. It will expand or reduce the image size until the shortest dimension fills that layout. Anything in the longer dimension that doesn't fit is cropped to that dimension's screen edges.

"Scale to fill" is the one that distorts. Posting this just in case someone sees your response.